# How can I get USDT Test Token

Tags: erc-20, ropsten

Can Anyone guide me on how to get the tether(usdt) test token on ethereum in ropsten test network

Answer (score 4):

You could just deploy an ERC20 token with a name of Tether, then call the mint function to populate your wallet with tokens and pretend this is Tether for testing purposes. Here's an example:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.7;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

import { ERC20 } from "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";


contract MockTether is ERC20 {

    string public version = "0.0.1";
    string public constant name = "Tether";
    string public constant symbol = "USDT";
    uint8 public constant decimals = 18;
    uint256 public constant MOCK_SUPPLY = 100e18;

    constructor() public {
        _mint(msg.sender, MOCK_SUPPLY);
    }

    function mint(address account, uint value) public {
        _mint(account, value);
    }

}
```

This would only really work if you have control over the other contracts that you want to act as if this is Tether (i.e. if you are building the other contracts as well).